# Not able to test time related hook in vitest

Tags: react-hooks, react-testing-library, vitest

Context: I am trying to write test cases for a custom react hook with internally uses time related api like setInterval. I am using `vi.useFakeTimers` to wrap the time related api and `renderHook` from `@testing/library/react` to render the hook.

Problem : I am trying to test if the mocked callback function is called `n` times in given timespan, but it is not being called even once.

Here is the custom react hook.

```
// useInterval.ts
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function useInterval(callback: () => void, delay: number | null) {
  const savedCallback = useRef<typeof callback>();

  useCallback(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current?.();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      const id = setInterval(tick, delay);

      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

export default useInterval;
```

and here is the test file.

```
// useInterval.test.ts
import { vi, expect, beforeEach, it, afterEach } from "vitest";
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react";
import useInterval from "./useInterval";

describe("useInterval", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    vi.useFakeTimers();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    vi.useRealTimers();
  });

  test("should call the callback after the specified delay", () => {
    const mockCallback = vi.fn();

    const delay = 100;

    renderHook(() => useInterval(mockCallback, delay));

    vi.advanceTimersByTime(200);

    expect(mockCallback).toBeCalled(); // -> AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called at least once
  });
});
```

Here is my dependencies version -

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.2",
"@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
"jsdom": "^24.0.0",
"vitest": "1.3.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've mistakenly used the `useCallback` hook instead of the `useEffect` hook to cache the callback function. The `useCallback` hook memoizes ***and returns*** a function that would then need to be called in order for the body to execute and actually set the `savedCallback` ref value. The `useEffect` hook callback is invoked when the dependency changes.

Swap out the `useCallback` for the `useEffect` hook so the passed `callback` reference is correctly cached in the `savedCallback` ref.

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function useInterval(callback: () => void, delay: number | null) {
  const savedCallback = useRef<typeof callback>();

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current?.();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      const id = setInterval(tick, delay);

      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

export default useInterval;
```